# jquery event where clicking a hyperlink switches the class of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to reveal a hidden div when a hyperlink (with an anchor on the hidden div) is clicked. My research has led me to believe that using .switchClass is the way to go, but for the life of me I haven't been able to get it to work. Here's what I've got:

**HTML**

```
<!-- link -->
<div id="rightnest">
    <p>
        You likely have a few questions, and maybe some of them can
        <br>be answered
        <a href="#questions" class="smoothScroll">
            <ins>here</ins>
        </a>.
    </p>
</div>

<!-- hidden div that should gain .centernest on click -->
<div class="hide">
    <p> a lot of text</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide {
    height: 400px;
    left: 200px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 700px;
}
.centernest {
    height: 400px;
    left: 200px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 700px;
}
```

there's .hide p, .hide h1, hide p a:link as well – all with visibility:hidden; (same for the .centernest class)

**JavaScipt**

```
$(function() {
    $("<ins>here</ins>").click(function(){
        $(".hide").switchClass("hide", "centernest", 100);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: change the selector: `$("<ins>here</ins>")` to this: `$(".smoothScroll")` and `visibility:hidden;` just make the element invisible it does not hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Call the click event with the hyperlink class.

```
$(function() {
        $(".smoothScroll").click(function(){
            $(".hide").switchClass("hide", "centernest", 100);
            return false;
        });
 });
```

Comment: I was pretty optimistic, with the .smoothScroll selector in place, I was going to have success – unfortunately not. Could there be a problem because I'm asking two .js events to happen (smoothScroll and switchClass) on the same event, but in two seperate <script></script> (s)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$(function() {
    $(".smoothScroll").click(function(){
      $(".hide").css( "visibility", "visible" );
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8kgcxok/)

Comment: Thanks for getting me on the right track with the selector. I've made some progress, but there's still some problems. Not all the elements become visible (there are different css classes on elements within the div)  and what does become visible has lost any CSS besides "visible". I'm going to keep working at it, but if you have a suspicion as to why that is happening please share :)

Comment: I just got everthing working :) Thanks so much for your help!